# pytest-django: Is this the right way to test view with parameters?

Tags: python, django, pytest, django-testing, pytest-django

Say I'm testing an RSS feed view in a Django app, is this how I should go about it?

```
def test_some_view(...):
    ...
    requested_url = reverse("personal_feed", args=[some_profile.auth_token])
    resp = client.get(requested_url, follow=True)
    ...
    assert dummy_object.title in str(resp.content)
```

1. Is `reverse`-ing and then passing that into the `client.get()` the right way to test? I thought it's DRYer and more future-proof than simply `.get()`ing the URL.
2. Should I assert that `dummy_object` is in the response this way?
3. I'm testing here using the `str` representation of the response object. When is it a good practice to do this vs. using `selenium`? I know it makes it easier to verify that said `obj` or property (like `dummy_object.title`) is encapsulated within an `H1` tag for example. On the other hand, if I don't care about *how* the obj is represented, it's faster to do it like the above.

Comment: 1. Using `reverse` is IMO the correct way - you are testing not against URLs, but against Django views, which are being accessed by name. 2. AFAIK the content is a raw bytestring; it should be decoded using `resp.charset` first. Usually, I only test status codes of HTML responses in unit tests; the content is better to test with `selenium` in e2e tests, but for simple pages your check should also suffice.

Comment: @hoefling - Can you maybe expand on `resp.charset` and how is `selenium` different in this context? I know what selenium is used for and that it can make the test cover HTML, etc..., but in case I just want to test whether some `obj` is in some part/QuerySet, doesn't this save time vs `selenium`? (maybe add this as an answer so I can mark it)

Comment: Ah, I didn't read your question carefully - indeed, in case of an RSS feed my comment makes no sense since it's not a `text/html` response :-)

Comment: @hoefling - still, some insight on when to use this vs. `selenium` would be golden. Should I ask a different question? or is it suitable here?

Comment: Great. I’ll edit the question slightly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reevaluating my comment (didn't carefully read the question and overlooked the RSS feed stuff):

> 1. Is `reverse`-ing and then passing that into the `client.get()` the right way to test? I thought it's DRYer and more future-proof than simply `.get()`ing the URL.

I would agree on that - from Django point, you are testing your views and don't care about what the exact endpoints they are mapped against. Using `reverse` is thus IMO the clear and correct approach.

> 2. Should I assert that `dummy_object` is in the response this way?

You have to pay attention here. `response.content` is a bytestring, so asserting `dummy_object.title in str(resp.content)` is dangerous. Consider the following example:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed

class MyFeed(Feed):
    title = 'äöüß'
    ...
```

Registered the feed in `urls`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('my-feed/', MyFeed(), name='my-feed'),
]
```

Tests:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_feed_failing(client):
    uri = reverse('news-feed')
    resp = client.get(uri)
    assert 'äöüß' in str(resp.content)


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_feed_passing(client):
    uri = reverse('news-feed')
    resp = client.get(uri)
    content = resp.content.decode(resp.charset)
    assert 'äöüß' in content
```

One will fail, the other won't because of the correct encoding handling.

As for the check itself, personally I always prefer parsing the content to some meaningful data structure instead of working with raw string even for simple tests. For example, if you are checking for data in a `text/html` response, it's not much more overhead in writing

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
assert soup.select_one('h1#title-headliner') == '<h1>title</h1>'
```

or

```
root = lxml.etree.parse(io.StringIO(content), lxml.etree.HTMLParser())
assert next(root.xpath('//h1[@id='title-headliner']')).text == 'title'
```

than just

```
assert 'title' in content
```

However, invoking a parser is more explicit (you won't accidentally test for e.g. the title in page metadata in `head`) and also makes an implicit check for data integrity (e.g. you know that the payload is indeed valid HTML because parsed successfully).

To your example: in case of RSS feed, I'd simply use the XML parser:

```
from lxml import etree

def test_feed_title(client):
    uri = reverse('my-feed')
    resp = client.get(uri)
    root = etree.parse(io.BytesIO(resp.content))
    title = root.xpath('//channel/title')[0].text
    assert title == 'my title'
```

Here, I'm using [`lxml`](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) which is a faster impl of stdlib's `xml`. The advantage of parsing the content to an XML tree is also that the parser reads from bytestrings, taking care about the encoding handling - so you don't have to decode anything yourself.

Or use something high-level like [`atoma`](https://pypi.org/project/atoma/) that ahs a nice API specifically for RSS entities, so you don't have to fight with XPath selectors:

```
import atoma

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_feed_title(client):
    uri = reverse('my-feed')
    resp = client.get(uri)
    feed = atoma.parse_atom_bytes(resp.content)
    assert feed.title.value == 'my title'
```

---

> 3. ...When is it a good practice to do this vs. using `selenium`?

Short answer - you don't need it. I havent't paid much attention when reading your question and had HTML pages in mind when writing the comment. Regarding this `selenium` remark - this library handles all the low-level stuff, so when the tests start to accumulate in count (and usually, they do pretty fast), writing

```
uri = reverse('news-feed')
resp = client.get(uri)
root = parser.parse(resp.content)
assert root.query('some-query')
```

and dragging the imports along becomes too much hassle, so `selenium` can replace it with

```
driver = WebDriver()
driver.get(uri)
assert driver.find_element_by_id('my-element').text == 'my value'
```

Sure, testing with an automated browser instance has other advantages like seeing exactly what the user would see in real browser, allowing the pages to execute client-side javascript etc. But of course, all of this applies mainly to HTML pages testing; in case of testing against the RSS feed `selenium` usage is an overkill and Django's testing tools are more than enough.